# php preg_replace matches

Tags: php, regex

How do you access the matches in preg_replace as a usable variable?  Here's my sample code:

```
<?php
$body = <<<EOT
Thank you for registering at <!-- site_name -->

Your username is: <!-- user_name -->

<!-- signature -->
EOT;

$value['site_name'] = "www.thiswebsite.com";
$value['user_name'] = "user_123";

$value['signature'] = <<<EOT
live long and prosper
EOT;

//echo preg_replace("/<!-- (#?\w+) -->/i", "[$1]", $body);
echo preg_replace("/<!-- (#?\w+) -->/i", $value[$1], $body);
?>
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   '$', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE
>   on line 18

The above remarked line with "[$i]" works fine when the match variable is enclosed in a quotes.  Is there a bit of syntax I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this: `echo preg_replace("/<!-- (#?\w+) -->/", '$1', $body);`

The `/i` modifier can only do harm to a pattern with no cased letters in it, incidentally.

Comment: I need to use the $1 to index $value[$1].

Comment: @gurun8: Then you need to use `preg_replace_callback()` so you can execute code upon each match.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `preg_replace` this way. It doesn't define a variable named `$1` that you can interact without outside the replacement; the string `'$1'` is simply used internally to represent the first sub-expression of the pattern.

You'll have to use a `preg_match` to find the string matched by `(#?\w+)`, followed by a `preg_replace` to replace matched string with the corresponding `$value`:

```
$value['site_name'] = "www.thiswebsite.com";
$value['user_name'] = "user_123";
$value['signature'] = "something else";

$matches = array();
$pattern = "/<!-- (#?\w+) -->/i";

if (preg_match($pattern, $body, $matches)) {
  if (array_key_exists($matches[1], $value)) {
    $body = preg_replace($pattern, '<!-- ' . $value[$matches[1]] . ' -->', $body);
  }
}

echo $body;
```