# replace with string between pattern

Tags: php, xml, replace, preg-replace

I have a question. I want to read a wrong xml format with the php function simplexml_load_string but I get empty values because the format is worng. Part of the xml:

```
<column name="price"><![CDATA[184.95]]></column>
<column name="category"><![CDATA[Dames]]></column>
<column name="subcategory"><![CDATA[Schoenen]]></column>
<column name="stock"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
```

I need to replace it to this:

```
<price><![CDATA[184.95]]></price>
<category><![CDATA[Dames]]></category>
<subcategory><![CDATA[Schoenen]]></subcategory>
<stock><![CDATA[1]]></stock>
```

to read the xml feed properly. Is it possible to replace this with `preg_match` for example? And how?

Comment: XSLT was defined for exactly that - converting one XML into another.

Comment: You do not necessarily get empty values only because of that XML. It looks fine. You probably don't know how to access it? Just commenting not that you ask the wrong way around and that you solve a programming problem in a way that works diametral against what you want to achieve (like using a regex in your accepted answer). Could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
$str = preg_replace('#<column name="([^"]+)">(.+?)</column>#', '<$1>$2</$1>', $str);
```

Comment: hi m42, this should be the solution but it isn't working. Even when i use regex tester http://regexpal.com/ it doesn't highlight the strings..

Answer (score 0):

The below would do it, but I think you could probably do it with `preg_replace`, see this link: [php preg_replace matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161041/php-preg-replace-matches)

```
preg_match_all('/<column name=\"([a-z]+)\">(.*)<\/column>/', $string, $matches);

$string = '';
foreach( $matches[1] as $key => $name )
{
    $string .= "<{$name}>{$matches[2][$key]}</{$name}>\n";
}
```